# Cart-qty value not change when i remove all product from cart in nopcommerce project

Tags: nopcommerce

When I add product into cart that time cart-qty value is show perfect but when I remove all product from cart that time its must be set to 0 but in my case my cart-qty value can't be change.

Its show me old added cart quantity into cart. When I restart my application from admin site that time my cart-qty value change.

And show me perfect value 0.

I can't  understand about this issue. Please Help me to solve this issue.
I try to remove Browser's cache and cookie but its show me old cart-qty value.

Comment: can you show how you are remove yr cart Qty so i can check and give you solution because without what way you use i can't provide you solution

Comment: Did you modify any code related to cart qty?